# How to retrieve component CreationDate in DXA 1.4 | SDL web8

Tags: web8, dxa

I am using SDL web8 with DXA1.4. I have the requirement to display the creation date of a multimedia component on the web page. I found

> BuildEntityModel
>    Method in the 
>   DefaultModelBuilder
>   class

does not add the creation date in the XMPMetadata of the componentpresentation.However I can see the ModifiedDate there.
Is there any way to retrieve component CreationDate inside the DXA without writing Event System or TBB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the regular CD API to retrieve this property as follows:

1. Construct a `ComponentMetaFactory`
2. Use the ComponentMetaFactory to get a IComponentMeta: `IComponentMeta myComponent = ComponentMetaFactory.GetMeta(<tcmId>);`
3. `var myCreationDate = myComponent.CreationDate`

Comment: You could put a `CreationDate` property on your View Model and create a custom Entity Controller which retrieves the date as described and sets the View Model property.